# mui datatables adding 'save' button on toolbar popover

Tags: reactjs, toolbar, popover, mui-datatable

I just want to be able to have save functionality when I'm add and removing columns in the toolbar popover so i can send that information server-side.

I can't seem to find a clear answer over how to modify or extend the toolbars popover ui. Perhaps saving column information is done differently. If so, I'm happy to hear about alternatives. Below are the current config and options for columns

```
let col = this.state.attributes.map(col => {

    let obj = {
      name: col.display_name,
      options: {
        filter: true,
        customBodyRender: (value) => (<div style={{whiteSpace:'nowrap'}}>{value}</div>)
      }
    }

    return obj

})
```

table options

```
const options = {
   filterType: "dropdown",
   responsive: "scrollMaxHeight",
   selectableRows: this.props.permissions.delete_contracts.display === 'enabled' ? 'multiple' : 'none',
   pagination: false,
   elevation: 5,
   onRowsDelete: this.onRowsDelete
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using the new method - onViewColumnsChange - when what I really needed was the old method - onColumnsViewChange. Someone has too much time on their hands to be making this change. I don't really need a custom button, so long as I can collect column names and actions.